# Vue module not applying CSS automatically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I made a Vue module for myself and published to NPM, but when I try to install this module to another project via `npm i <module-name>`, I can use component, but it's not applying CSS for my component.

I think the problem is I am writing all CSS in **style scope** in my component. I don't know what the best practice is for including CSS. My style is so simple like this:

```
<style>
.container {
  border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  position: relative;
}
.image-container {
    height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 7%;
}
.title-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center; /* optional */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  border-top: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;

}
</style>
```

Comment: Your style is not having the scope attribute. You might want to try that.

Comment: Do your component styles show up in DevTools Styles list, but are overridden?

Comment: @ourmandave No. It's not showing up

Comment: @FirstIndex I also tried that. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For a library, it might be more convenient (and less error-prone) for your users if you include the CSS in your bundle, so users wouldn't have to import the CSS themselves. This is also recommended in the Vue CLI [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-extract). To do this, set [`css.extract=true`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-extract) in `vue.config.js`:

*vue.config.js:*

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  css: {
    extract: true
  }
}
```